# How do I get an array of admin menu items?

Tags: admin, magento2.3.3, adminmenu, bin-magento

I am trying to get an array of all registered admin menu items that can be used from a `bin/magento` command to help choose a parent item to build a child item for. I have tried using `\Magento\Backend\Model\Menu\Config->getMenu()` but any of the methods on the returned model result in an empty array.

Answer (score 1):

`\Magento\Backend\Model\Menu\Config::getMenu()->toArray()`  should work, but it only works on `adminhtml` because the `menu.xml` config files are declared for `adminhtml` scope.
Maybe you can try calling this before retrieving the menu: `Magento\Framework\App\State::emulateAreaCode('adminhtml')`. (of course don't call it static. use and instance of `Magento\Framework\App\State`)

`emulateAreaCode` accepts 3 parameters.

- the area code (adminhtml in your case)
- a callback that can be a method call that retrieves your menu
- params for the callback.

Haven't tried it so not sure if this works or is a total waste of time.